# Stream from a temporary file, then delete when finished?

Tags: php, stream, php-7, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm writing a temporary file by running a couple of external Unix tools over a PDF file (basically I'm using QPDF and sed to alter the colour values. Don't ask.):

```
// Uncompress PDF using QPDF (doesn't read from stdin, so needs tempfile.)
$compressed_file_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cruciverbal');
file_put_contents($compressed_file_path, $response->getBody());  
$uncompressed_file_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cruciverbal');
$command = "qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable '$compressed_file_path' '$uncompressed_file_path'";
exec($command, $output, $return_value);

// Run through sed (could do this bit with streaming stdin/stdout)
$fixed_file_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cruciverbal');
$command = "sed s/0.298039215/0.0/g < '$uncompressed_file_path' > '$fixed_file_path'";
exec($command, $output, $return_value);
```

So, when this is done I'm left with a temporary file on disk at `$fixed_file_path`. (NB: While I could do the whole `sed` process streamed in-memory without a tempfile, the QPDF utility [requires an actual file as input](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/54), for good reasons.)

In my existing process, I then read the whole `$fixed_file_path` file in as a string, delete it, and hand the string off to another class to go do things with.

I'd now like to change that last part to using a PSR-7 stream, i.e. a `\Guzzle\Psr7\Stream` object. I figure it'll be more memory-efficient (I might have a few of these in the air at once) and it'll need to be a stream in the end.

However, I'm not sure then how I'd delete the temporary file when the (third-party) class I'd handed the stream off to is finished with it. Is there a method of saying "...and delete that when you're finished with it"? Or auto-cleaning my temporary files in some other way, without keeping track of them manually?

I'd been vaguely considering rolling my own `SelfDestructingFileStream`, but that seemed like overkill and I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: `shell_exec` will return the full output from the command. Why are you outputting to a file at all?

Comment: @mpen Well, basically because it was a quick and dirty process in the first place. I'm now trying to clean it up, and I'll certainly be considering reading the result of `sed` directly from the process. However, I seem to remember that QPDF, the preceding process, doesn't handle streaming that well, possibly because PDFs aren't that "streamy" (they're not written in useful order for streaming), so I had a temporary file lying around already.

Comment: You're introducing overhead by adding in `\Guzzle\Psr7\Stream` unless you already have classes that work with Guzzle/PSR7 streams. PHP has built-in support for streams if you use the right methods. QPDF may need to buffer the entire file into memory before it starts processing it, and it might not output anything either until it's fully done, but you can still use streams on the PHP side of things. If it utilises them, great! More memory savings. If not, I don't think it hurts any.

Comment: @mpen I do have classes that work with PSR7 streams; the file is eventually destined for a Guzzle POST request, so I think it would be more memory efficient as a stream. And yes, [I was remembering right](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/54); QPDF needs to read the whole thing in before it processes it, so it doesn't take from stdin.

Comment: Oh..but you wrote `< '$uncompressed_file_path'`. That sends the file through stdin. Does that not work? If it it only reads and writes to files, I think you'll have to create a `tmpfile()` and then `unlink()` it when you're done. There's no way to have it delete itself automatically as far as I'm aware. You could create a class to wrap it and add a destructor (`__destruct`) to it if you want.

Comment: @mpen Sorry, yes, I've now tried to clarify my question. (I'd skipped a bit of reasoning because I'd already considered using `sed` with in/out streams. Really it's the QPDF process that's the issue.)

Comment: Per the documentation of `tmpfile()` it actually does delete the file when it's closed. So... yeah, I'd say roll your own class that wraps that. There may or may not be something out there already, but it shouldn't take you very long to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is something like this:

```
<?php

class TempFile implements \Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface {

    private $resource;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->resource = tmpfile();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    public function getFilename() {
        return $this->getMetadata('uri');
    }

    public function getMetadata($key = null) {
        $data = stream_get_meta_data($this->resource);
        if($key) {
            return $data[$key];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function close() {
        fclose($this->resource);
    }

    // TODO: implement methods from https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/StreamInterface.php
}
```

Have QPDF write to `$tmpFile->getFilename()` and then you can pass the whole object off to your Guzzle/POST since it's PSR-7 compliant and then the file will delete itself when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, that approach seems to be working fine. I used the handy [StreamDecoratorTrait](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7#implementing-stream-decorators) to avoid having to manually implement the other stream methods.

Comment: @MattGibson Oh nice. Didn't know about that trait. Thanks for sharing :-D

Comment: No problem. It's nice to have some reassurance that my vague plans were heading along roughly sane lines...